# struct recursive memory handling issues

Tags: c

I have built a binary search tree for my program. This is my code:

```
struct node {
    int steps;
    int x;
    int y;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*head;

typedef  struct node *Node;

Node createStepsBinaryTree(Node head, int newStepsInt, int x, int y){
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = (Node)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (head==NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }else{
            head->steps = newStepsInt;
            head->x = x;
            head->y = y;
            head->left = head->right = NULL;
        }
    }else{
        if (head->steps > newStepsInt) {
            head->left = createStepsBinaryTree(head->left, newStepsInt, x, y);
        }else{
            head->right = createStepsBinaryTree(head->right, newStepsInt, x, y);
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

This is how i call this function from another recursive function:

```
Coor insertDataToTree(Node stepsTree,Coor root, int x, int y, int map[length][length], int steps){

    steps++;
    stepsTree = createStepsBinaryTree(stepsTree, steps, x, y);
    .
    .
    .
```

And this is how i'm entering it to that recursive function:

```
Node stepsTree = NULL;

root = insertDataToTree(stepsTree,root, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, map, startPoint.steps);
```

Now for the main issue i'm having:
It runs great the first two runs, but then it runs for the third time through the two structs that are in that tree, but the when it should give itself a NULL struct it gives something that is REALLY close to NULL. It shows (Node *)0x000000000000000000001.

Does anyone know how can i stop this madness?? :)

Comment: `head = (Node)malloc(sizeof(Node));` allocates just enough space for a pointer, where a whole struct is intended. (this problem is probably caused by the confusion caused by the hiding of a pointer behind a typedef)

Comment: If you remove the (unnecessary) casting of `malloc()`'s result, does this give you a warning then?

Comment: `sizeof(*head)` rather than `sizeof(Node)` would probably suit you better for this.

Answer (score 1):

As @wildplasser noted, you're allocating enough space for a Node, which is a pointer type.  You either need to change your code so that Node is a struct or allocate sizeof(struct node) bytes in your malloc.

I strongly suggest you not hide your pointer in a typedef - this is one of several examples of how that causes problems.

Comment: I tried using Gilberts advice, but it only helped for a few more runs. After a while it happened again...

Comment: Once you've made that change, I don't see anything wrong with createStepsBinaryTree.  The problem is likely with code you have omitted from your example.  That said, the fact that insertDataToTree doesn't return the new tree the first time is quite suspicious.  How are you adding multiple nodes to the tree through that function?

Answer (score 0):

```
head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof( struct node ) )
```

though sizeof(*Node) is accepted by most compilers.

Comment: Ok… I tried using your solution and it did help for a few more runs but after a while it happens again

Comment: @user1461635: Or even better just do: `head = malloc(sizeof(*head));` then it does matter what `head` is pointing to. This way `malloc()` **always** allocates the correct amount of memory, namely the size of what `head` is declared to point to.